# Specifying folder paths in R

Tags: r, windows, directory

I have a folder structure which looks like the following. I have a file which needs to be processed in the Data folder. After processing I'll be writing 2 files to Results folder and the Log folder. (I use R in a windows environment).

[image]

Below is my R code for setting the folder paths for files:

```
setwd("E:/Assignment")

myData = read.csv("E:/Assignment/Data/accident_rates.csv")
myResultsFileLoc = "E:/Assignment/Results/accident_rates_accumilated.csv"
myLogFileLoc = "E:/Assignment/Results/accident_rates_accumilated_Log.csv"

write.table(results, myResultsFileLoc,...)
write.table(results, myLogFileLoc ,...)
```

As I have already set the working directory to "E:/Assignment", I don't want to repeat this part for the sub folders when setting the paths for other files. Is there anyway to instruct R the folder is a sub folder of the set working directory (without specifying the complete path)? I tried using the below methods but it gives me errors.

```
myResultsFileLoc = "/Results/accident_rates_accumilated.csv" 
myResultsFileLoc = "~/Results/accident_rates_accumilated.csv"
```

I'm looking for this solution because my folder structure might expand and it would be bit difficult to maintain the folder path for each and every file in the sub folder.

Comment: "." mean the current directory, "../" means the previous.  So, "./Results/..." should work, or simply "Results/..."

Comment: Thank you vey much @nongkrong it worked!

Comment: you can use `path.expand('~')` to find out what `~` is expanding to, I doubt it is `E:/Assignments`